# ElasticSearch Springboot NativeSearchQueryBuilder issue

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

Question
I am not getting any function call as mentioned below in all website for calling `NativeSearchQueryBuilder()` as follows

```
SearchQuery searchQuery = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder()
.withQuery(matchQuery("title", "spring date elasticsearch")
.operator(AND)
.fuzziness(Fuzziness.ONE)
.prefixLength(3))
.build();
```

When i start calling `NativeSearchQueryBuilder().withQuery(matchQuery())`, matchQuery does not come. MatchQuery, MatchQueryBuilder all these are coming instead of it. So can you please tell me how can create fuzzy search with `NativeSearchQueryBuilder()`.

> SpringBoot version - 1.5.4
>   spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch - 1.5.4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`matchQuery` is a static method from `org.elasticsearch.index.query.QueryBuilders`. So you have to import it statically.

Usage without import should look as below:

```
SearchQuery searchQuery = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder()
  .withQuery(
    org.elasticsearch.index.query.QueryBuilders.matchQuery("title", "spring date elasticsearch")
      .operator(AND)
      .fuzziness(Fuzziness.ONE)
      .prefixLength(3)
  ).build();
```